# How to copy one tablerow to another table using listrow?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy data rows from different tables and usually i would setup a conveluted setup
counting rows and columns and a couple of level deep for loops.

However, it appears the modern way to go is using listrows.
I tried going over the guide always referenced at https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/6/20/the-vba-guide-to-listobject-excel-tables

However i seem to miss this  "sometable.listobject(1).rows = differentable.listrow(1).rows"  roughly...

My code

```
Sub GenerateOverview()
Dim MainWs As Worksheet
Set MainWs = Worksheets("Overview")
Dim mainTbl As ListObject
Set mainTbl = MainWs.ListObjects(1)

' Later add for each sheet ----

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("ABD")   ' ABD to be replaced with activesheet.name LATER
Dim tbl As ListObject
Set tbl = ws.ListObjects(1)

Dim TopXRange As Integer
TopXRange = 10  ' to be changed to user defined range

Dim i As Integer
i = 0

For i = 1 To TopXRange
    mainTbl.DataBodyRange.Rows(i) = tbl.DataBodyRange.Rows(i)
      ' THIS only produces empty cells on maintbl and not the content from tbl. 
Next i

' end for each sheet ----

End Sub
```

Any advice?

**Working solution for my task..**

```
Sub GenerateOverview()
Dim MainWs As Worksheet
Set MainWs = Worksheets("Overview")
Dim mainTbl As ListObject
Set mainTbl = MainWs.ListObjects(1)

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim TopXRange As Integer
TopXRange = 10
Dim i As Integer
i = 1
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim newI
Dim mainRows As Integer

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    If ws.Name = MainWs.Name Then GoTo skip

    Set ws = Worksheets(ws.Name)
    Set tbl = ws.ListObjects(1)

    mainRows = mainTbl.ListRows.Count
    If mainRows = 0 Then mainRows = 1

    For i = newI To TopXRange

        mainTbl.ListRows.Add (mainRows)
        mainTbl.ListRows(mainRows).Range.Value = tbl.ListRows(i + 1).Range.Value

    Next i


skip:
Next
End sub
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: My question is,  Can i use listobject(x)  to copy and entire row and then paste it into another listobject(y) 

Like   listobject(y).listrows(newrow) = listobject(x).listrows(currentcount)    ?

I tried this..  But it only copies EMPTY cells

mainTbl.DataBodyRange.Rows(i) = tbl.DataBodyRange.Rows(i)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still not sure I follow. You probably need to insert a row into your second table before transferring. Something like this works:

```
Sub x()

Dim t1 As ListObject, t2 As ListObject

Set t1 = Sheet1.ListObjects("Table1")
Set t2 = Sheet1.ListObjects("Table2")

t2.ListRows.Add (3) 'insert new row 3 into second table
t2.ListRows(3).Range.Value = t1.ListRows(4).Range.Value 'transfer to new row from first table

End Sub
```

Comment: This is excaktly what i needed..

Working now ;) 
Putting in my working solution at the top, thank you.

Comment: Good, perhaps you could accept the answer. You should also check the two tables are the same width.